# If I reinstall MySql Workbech will i lose my data bases and saved connections?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, reinstall

When I start Workbench it pops up a message saying

> Error while loading images: An error occurred while loading image search_sidebar.png.

Then I can't connect with my databases. I searched in MySQL forums and apparently that is a bug without resolving yet, and the only thing to do is reinstalling the program.

So, my question is simple: `reinstalling workbench will make me lose my databases and connections?` Im principally worried about de DB's.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql workbench is a standalone software. It won't affect your MySQL databases. It's same as removing phpMyAdmin from your server won't affect your databases.

Comment: Thanks man, its just that i didn't do it before, so I was insecure about it.

Comment: Great! I guess you may want to mark this as correct answer :)